# Using Pyspark how to convert Text file to CSV file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new learner for Pyspark. I got a requirement in my project to read JSON file with a schema and need to convert it to CSV file.

Can  some one help me how to proceed this request using PYspark.

Comment: You can use simple python to write a json file as csv. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Comment: Actually i cannot go with alternative approach. We have to go for Pyspark code only

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of **your attempts** as well as examples of your inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 0):

You can load JSON and write CSV with SparkSession.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("ETL").getOrCreate()
spark.read.json(path-to-txt)
spark.write.csv(path-to-csv)
```

Comment: Actually i have 2 file as an input, first one is text file with data and 2nd file is json file which has schema. I need to read the text file using that schema from json file and write into csv format without header?